# Subgroups of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{C})$ acting properly discontinuously and freely on $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: riemann-surfaces, automorphism-group

I am trying to figure out why the following statement from my lecture notes is true and would appreciate any help; a statement in my lecture notes in Riemann surface stated that "Any subgroup $\Gamma$ of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{C})$ acting properly discontinuously and freely on $\mathbb{C}$ must be trivial or conjugate to $\mathbb{Z}$ or to a lattice $\mathbb{Z} + \tau \mathbb{Z}$."

I can see that the statement holds true for the first 2 cases where $\Gamma$ is trivial and single-generated respectively. How do I show the last case?

Comment: Do you know/is it clear to you that the problem is equivalent to characterising the discrete subgroups of $(\mathbb{C},+)$?

Comment: Hi Daniel, my lecturer briefly mentioned this but he did not went into the details.

Comment: An automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ is of the form $z \mapsto az + b$ with $a \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ and $b \in \mathbb{C}$. If $a \neq 1$, then this automorphism has the unique fixed point $\frac{b}{1-a}$. Thus the group acting freely implies that it consists of translations. You can then identify each $\gamma \in \Gamma$ with $\gamma(0)$, and it's easy to check that this gives an isomorphism with a subgroup of $(\mathbb{C},+)$. The image is the orbit of $0$, and that the action is properly discontinuous implies that that is discrete. Conversely, for a discrete subgroup $G$ the group of…

Comment: …translations $z \mapsto z + g$ with $g \in G$ acts freely and properly discontinuous. Thus the next question is, have you an idea how to characterise the discrete subgroups of $\mathbb{C}$?